# Date from two strings on android

Tags: java, android, date-parsing

I have two strings for a date (using the current year):

1. a day = "15"
2. a month = "7"

With this data I would like to have a string date with this format: `Tuesday July 15`

Is that possible?

I´m trying with this code but it doesn't work:

```
 public void dateFormatMoth(String day, String month){

 Date date = null;

    String newDateStr="";
    String dateReceived="day/month";

    SimpleDateFormat fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
    SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE-MM-dd");

    try {

         reformattedStr = myFormat.format(fromUser.parse(dateReceived));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

   Log.d(LOG_TAG,"day formatted"+newDateStr);
}
```

Comment: Your logging statement logs `newDateStr`, which you never set to anything but the empty string.

Comment: pretty sure you just forgot to parse date

Comment: @user1071777 of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `myFormat` slightly to achieve this. `MM` will give you month as number, `MMMM` will give you the full name:

```
public void dateFormatMonth(String day, String month) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
    SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE MMMM dd", Locale.US);
    try {
        reformattedStr = myFormat.format(fromUser.parse(day + "/" + month));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG,"day formatted"+newDateStr);
}
```

You can read more about the different formats in the [JavaDoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Note that I specified the locale explicitly, to make sure you got the output you requested regardless of the locale of your machine.

Answer (score 1):

### [`java.time.MonthDay#of(int month, int dayOfMonth)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html#of-int-int-)

You can use `MonthDay#of(int month, int dayOfMonth)` to create an instance of `MonthDay` out of the given month and the day of the month.

### You need a year

Every year 15-Jul may fall on a different day of the week e.g. in 2014, it falls on Tuesday and in the current year 2023, it falls on Saturday. So, you need a year to get the day of the week out of the `MonthDay`.

By assigning a year to the `MonthDay`, you get a `LocalDate` which can give you the day of the week and many other pieces of information e.g. week number, whether it is before/after another day etc.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.MonthDay;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(weekdayMonthDayFormatted("15", "7"));
    }

    static String weekdayMonthDayFormatted(String day, String month) {
        MonthDay md = MonthDay.of(Integer.parseInt(month), Integer.parseInt(day));

        // I have used 2014 here just for the demo. Replace 2014 with the applicable
        // year e.g. for the current year, replace it with Year.now().getValue()
        LocalDate date = md.atYear(2014);

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE MMMM dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
        return date.format(formatter);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Tuesday July 15
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/LbGVDR)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Note**: In Mar 2014, the `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` were supplanted by the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). Since then, it is highly recommended to stop using the legacy date-time API.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    public static String format(String input_date, String input_format, String output_format) {

        SimpleDateFormat simple_date_input_format;
        SimpleDateFormat simple_date_output_format;
        simple_date_input_format = new SimpleDateFormat(input_format, Locale.US);
        simple_date_output_format = new SimpleDateFormat(output_format, Locale.US);

        try {
            Date input_date_formatted = simple_date_input_format.parse(input_date);
            output_date_formatted = simple_date_output_format.format(input_date_formatted);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            output_date_formatted = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output_date_formatted;
```